# Add sound theme to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound-theme

I am using almost default 18.04. I do not get any login or logout sounds. `usr/share/sounds` seems to have some folders in it. But there are no sound indicators for any activity I do on my PC. Is it possible to find and use a good sound theme with 18.04 ? If yes, please tell me how.

Edit 1

[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the "Alert volume" through Sound settings?

Comment: I just tried. It was zero before that. I will update once I see the change. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for login sound edit the file `/usr/share/gnome/autostart/libcanberra-login-sound.desktop` and make the line `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` to `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true`

Modified Content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=GNOME Login Sound
Comment=Plays a sound whenever you log in
Exec=/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
AutostartCondition=GSettings org.gnome.desktop.sound event-sounds
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Application
X-GNOME-Provides=login-sound
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
NoDisplay=true
```

For logout sound, there is a reported bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/214370 I tried to make it happen but failed..

you can look for sound themes from this link https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/08/how-install-sound-themes-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP I will try and update.

Comment: There is only `Gnome Login Sound` under /usr/share/gnome/autostart

Comment: tried without success. What to do now ?

Comment: Thanks @PRATAP . It is 'freedesktop'

Comment: The sound played, only after I entered the password. I have updated the question with sound themes list. Can I use Yaru ? What is the command for it ?

Comment: I see. Can you tell me the method for the startup sound as well, please ?